# How to integrate Carrierwave-Dropox gem with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, dropbox-api

I'm using this gem [carrierwave-dropbox](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox) and I have an error while trying to upload my file. I have an error "`Forbidden`". Do I need to place the Carrierwave configuration in application.rb or in a separate file in /config/  ? here is my configuration:

Rails 4.0.2 on local

1. I have a foo_bar folder in Dropbox (app folder name)

   ```
   rake dropbox:authorize APP_KEY=abcMY_APP_KEYcdf APP_SECRET=foo_APP_SECRET_bar ACCESS_TYPE=dropbox
   ```
2. I get prompt online with

   > foo_bar would like to create a folder in your Dropbox. This app will only have access to files in the new "foo_bar" folder in your Apps folder.
3. Than on my command line I have

   ```
   access_token: abcdefghigklmnop  
   access_token_secret: abcdefghijklmnoo  
   user_id: 123456789
   ```
4. On my application.rb :

   ```
   CarrierWave.configure do |config|
     config.dropbox_app_key = "abcMY_APP_KEYcdf"
     config.dropbox_app_secret = "foo_APP_SECRET_bar"
     config.dropbox_access_token = "abcdefghigklmnop "
     config.dropbox_access_token_secret = "abcdefghijklmnoo"
     config.dropbox_user_id = 123456789
     config.dropbox_access_type = "dropbox"
   end
   ```

Comment: Hope I got everything right with my editing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a file in `config/initializers` directory say `carrierwave.rb` and place the Carrierwave-dropbox related configurations in it. See the example: in [carrierwave-dropbox](https://github.com/robin850/carrierwave-dropbox/blob/master/spec/dummy/config/initializers/carrierwave.rb) repo.